# Мультиязычность приложений Android

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте!

Как организовать мультиязычность в Android правильно? Имею ввиду на основе ресурсов и автоматический выбор необходимого языка в зависимости от языка системы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Прочтите соответствующую документацию. Про это всё написано:

- [Application Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/index.html)
- [Translating Android applications](http://www.vogella.de/blog/2011/01/17/translating-android-applications-i18n/) (пример)

Да и вообще полно всего уже написано. Ключевые слова для поиска: Android i18n.